# Saving only the architecture of a TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I save and reload the architecture of a TensorFlow model without including the weight values? I'm looking for a TensorFlow equivalent of Keras' `model.to_json` and `keras.models.model_from_json` (though it doesn't have to be in a human-readable format).

Comment: You can use [`tf.io.write_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/write_graph) / [`tf.graph_util.import_graph_def`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/import_graph_def). You can also save more metadata with [`tf.train.export_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/export_meta_graph) / [`tf.train.import_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph), or with [`tf.train.Saver.export_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#export_meta_graph).